# Get dependences from parenthal array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration, parent-child

I have two arrays:

1. Array for print, each item is one row of table

   ```
   array(
     [1] => array(
       [data] = array(
         [parent] = NULL,
         [depth] = 1
       );
     );

     [2] => array(
       [data] = array(
         [parent] = 1,
         [depth] = 2
       );
     );

     [3] => array(
       [data] = array(
         [parent] = 1,
         [depth] = 2
       );
     );

     [4] => array(
       [data] = array(
         [parent] = 2,
         [depth] = 3
       );
     );


     [5] => array(
       [data] = array(
         [parent] = NULL,
         [depth] = 1
       );
     );

     [6] => array(
       [data] = array(
         [parent] = 5,
         [depth] = 2
       );
     );
   );
   ```
2. Array to order by dimensions

   ```
   array(
     [1] => array(
       [data] = array(
         [parent] = NULL,
         [depth] = 1
       );
       [children] => array(
         [2] => array(
           [data] = array(
             [parent] = 1,
             [depth] = 2
           );
           [children] => array(
             [4] => array(
               [data] = array(
                 [parent] = 2,
                 [depth] = 3
               );
             );
           );
         );

         [3] => array(
           [data] = array(
             [parent] = 1,
             [depth] = 2
           );
         );
       );
     );
     [5] => array(
       [data] = array(
         [parent] = NULL,
         [depth] = 1
       );
       [children] => array(
         [6] => array(
           [data] = array(
             [parent] = 5,
             [depth] = 2
           );
         );
       );
     );
   );
   ```

And I would like obtain this array (it doesn't matter from whitch):

```
    array(
      [1] => array(
        [1] = array(
          [parent] = NULL,
          [depth] = 1
        );
      );

      [2] => array(
        [1] = array(
          [parent] = NULL,
          [depth] = 1
        );
        [2] = array(
          [parent] = 1,
          [depth] = 2
        );
      );

      [3] => array(
        [1] = array(
          [parent] = NULL,
          [depth] = 1
        );
        [2] = array(
          [parent] = 1,
          [depth] = 2
        );
      );

      [4] => array(
        [1] = array(
          [parent] = NULL,
          [depth] = 1
        );
        [2] = array(
          [parent] = 1,
          [depth] = 2
        );
        [3] = array(
          [parent] = 2,
          [depth] = 3
        );
      );

      [5] => array(
        [1] = array(
          [parent] = NULL,
          [depth] = 1
        );
      );

      [6] => array(
        [1] = array(
          [parent] = NULL,
          [depth] = 1
        );
        [2] = array(
          [parent] = 5,
          [depth] = 2
        );
      );
    );
```

**It's array where I can see every parents by its id. Somebody knows?**

Comment: That's not valid array syntax, is it?

Comment: It's just example wrote for this question. You can imagine structure from that?